# How to store one symbol in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, char, nsmutabledictionary

I want to store one symbol '0' as NSMutableDictionary value. How can I do this? NSString is not appropriate because it creates a string not a single character and as far as I know there is no NSObject   representation of char data type in Objective-C.

So the question how can I implement this. If you will advice me to use NSValue for this then I need an example how to wrap '0' in it.

Comment: set NSNumber in NSMutableDictionary.is it you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setObject:forKey: and pass a NSNumber as the object:

```
[myMutableDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithChar:0] forKey:@"someKey"];
```

Comment: if you're working with char specifically it may be better to use numberWithChar: instead of numberWithInt: